# Linux's poweroff resets the machine instead of powering it off

Tags: linux, power, gnome3, poweroff, fedora-20

I'm using Fedora 20 with Gnome3, and sometimes when I click on Power Off, the machine resets instead of powering off. Actually I don't know if it's being reset or if it's being powered off and then it powers on by itself somehow (is that possible?). I can't see anything after I click on Power Off, because the Nvidia drivers give me a black screen in some places (eg: when I do ctrl + alt + FX, or when I reset/poweroff).

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Any logs I should look into?